# why does django authentication not recognize request.user variable?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10.  I have the following setup:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'IFTHQ',
    'rest_framework'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from IFTHQ import models
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    """A view of all bands."""
    return render(request, 'IFTHQ/publicpages/front.html')


@login_required(login_url="login/")
def dashboard(request):
    member = models.Member.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    data = {}
    data["profile"] = member
    return render(request, 'IFTHQ/dashboard/dashboard.html', {"data": data})

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def membership(request):
    data = {}
    data["profile"] = member
    return render(request, 'IFTHQ/dashboard/membership.html', {"data": data})
```

I confirmed that there's a member in the member object, however, when I log in, I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://<<domain>>/

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'IFTHQ',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/trekfed/IFTHQ/views.py" in dashboard
  14.     member = models.Member.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: Member matching query does not exist.
```

it seems like it doesn't find the member from the `request.user.id`.  what am I missing?  Thanks.

UPDATE 1:
Member Model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    FID = models.FloatField()
    backup_email = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    FName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    MName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    LName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Avatar = models.FileField(upload_to='Avatar/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    Cover = models.FileField(upload_to='Cover/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    Facebook = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    GooglePlus = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    Twitter = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    Website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    Bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    Hair_Choices = (
        ('Blond', 'Blond'),
        ('Black', 'Black'),
        ('Brown', 'Brown'),
        ('Brunette', 'Brunette'),
        ('Red', 'Red'),
        ('Auburn', 'Auburn'),
        ('Gray', 'Gray'),
        ('White', 'White'),
        ('Colorful', 'Colorful'),
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('N/A', 'Not Applicable')
    )
    Hair = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=Hair_Choices)
    Height = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FName + " " + self.LName

    def shortrank(self):
        return Rank.objects.filter(User=self.id).order_by("-date_promoted")[0].Rank.SName

    def currentrank(self):
        return Rank.objects.filter(User=self.id).order_by("-date_promoted")[0].Rank.LongName

    def rank_img(self):
        return Rank.objects.filter(User=self.id).order_by("-date_promoted")[0].Rank.image

    def primary_address(self):
        return MemberAddress.objects.get(AddressFK=self.id, Default=True)

    def primary_phone(self):
        return MemberPhone.objects.get(PhoneFK=self.id, Default=True)

    def awards(self):
        return Award.objects.filter(Member=self.id)
```

This screenshot shows that the connection does exist.

[image]

UPDATE 2:
models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...<More>...
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def dashboard(request):
    member = request.user.member
    data = {}
    data["profile"] = member
    return render(request, 'IFTHQ/dashboard/dashboard.html', {"data": data})
```

New Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: <<domain.com>>

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'IFTHQ',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/trekfed/IFTHQ/views.py" in dashboard
  14.     member = request.user.member

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  235.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

File "/home/arcee123/trekfed/env-trekfed/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  370.                     self.related.get_accessor_name()

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: User has no member.
```

Comment: "I confirmed that there's a member in the member object" what do you mean? What does the `Member` class look like?

Comment: Because there simply is no Member with an id that is equal to the relevant user id? `get_object_or_404` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: ok.  I updated the question.  this shows the model and value does exist.

Comment: And "member" is a user.

Answer (score 0):

`request.user.id` gives you the id from the user table. If you want to fetch the related member, then you should filter on the `user` field, not the id field.

```
member = models.Member.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
```

If you remove `related_name='user'` from your foreign key, then you could simply do:

```
member = request.user.member
```

With `related_name='user'`, you can do `member = request.user.user`. However, that's confusing because following the relationship backwards gives you a `Member`, not a `User`.

Comment: ok.  I did the first recommendation, and UPDATE 2 shows the response.  I just don't get why this works on my local machine, but the other server it dies.  THanks much.

Comment: As the error says, you haven't created a `Member` for the logged in user in the server's database. You either need to make sure that you always create a `Member` at the same time as the `User`, or you need to make your code handle the `DoesNotExist` exception.